# How to swap hotbars?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Medieval Engineers allows you to have multiple hotbars, in order to group your weapons on 1st, your house structures on 2nd, etc.

How to swap from the 1st to the 2nd, and back to the 1st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [old Steam forum post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/333950/discussions/0/618453594741953930/#c618453594741960122), a user posted that you use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>4</kbd> to change between them:

> Press Shift+1-4 to view the different hotbars

It now seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> according to [comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/398834/how-to-swap-hotbars/398852?noredirect=1#comment560473_398852).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I tested and found that currently it's CTRL.
Can you please update your answer?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah updated.